# How to Change the Default Search Engine in the Chromium in Android version code?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I've built Chromium for Android and I want to change default search engine in a good way in the Chromium code.

I didn't found any reference for doing that in chromium document.

How I should do it?Must I create an extension or change the SQLite data?